# How to get individual inference of generic array elements?

Tags: typescript, generics, types, typescript-generics

I have an array of objects. The type of those objects is generic, where some properties of each object are constrained by another property on the same object. I am having trouble getting the individual array elements to be inferred correctly without needing to define a function to help with the inference.

Here's some code to demonstrate:

```js
type Table = {
    schema: {
        [column: string]: string
    }
}

type Column<T extends Table = Table, N extends keyof T['schema'] = keyof T['schema']> = {
    table: T,
    name: N
}

function listOfColumns(columns: Column[]) {
    return columns
}

function column<T extends Table>(column: Column<T>) {
    return column
}

const t1 = {
    schema: {
        a: 'a',
        b: 'b'
    }
} satisfies Table

const t2 = {
    schema: {
        c: 'c',
        d: 'd'
    }
} satisfies Table

listOfColumns([
    {
        table: t1,
        name: 'a' // Valid
    },
    {
        table: t2,
        name: 'c' // Valid
    },
    {
        table: t2,
        name: 'x' // WRONG: Shouldn't be valid
    }
])

listOfColumns([
    column({
        table: t1,
        name: 'a' // Valid
    }),
    column({
        table: t2,
        name: 'c' // Valid
    }),
    column({
        table: t2,
        name: 'x' // RIGHT: Not valid
    })
])
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKghgIwDbQLxQN4Cgq6gZwGMALCAWzgC5Mc86BtQgeyQFcyA7a-YAJwEsOAcwC63PoKG1cAXyxysoSFADCLdhwA8MKBAAewCBwAm+WIhRR08ZBAA0UAHK6DR01ADWEEEwBmsegByIlIKQJErT28-AOCScjhwgD5I7DpgCwhqGDtpKA44MiyneSwsX1YOQmB+Jg4oJH4eAHlfNTZOfAAKZg6OfGp2jXoRAEoaOl4IYFZeet6NfFLyyura+fVObRdDEzMbFCSeza5VE+0k8bS8KZm5qAXOZeZ+4ChgAEZUvJCE6mu6LgqFBAolcoC8AhqIEEIE8nIZAQ4DV8L5+BB9pkyi8eO8AEzfOi-Cj-PJ0QjQwiBcEQqDGaHGOF0BFIlFojHmWxlRotNonbr0PIAwEZWzUT40iEFIrQxJQAD08qgADU4I1jPDJRNaaKUOK8Vq6NLioEqQqlar1ZqhWS8LrisADbbcMboXpAuaoAB1ABKzUcAHFqABlYhMVhIYwcQJvBDQABuav4GuZWDG3KawFaQ06XUF5JOXWF6Uy4o+hrwrpBcsVKqTKbwMlGWseHCLzvepfxFZdhRNZtrluT8ObeVb7dpnbF3Y7VcC7s9PoAkgGABIwaiOJhvRNW5mjNOjIA)

As you can see, when I pass in the object literals directly, I get no inference for each element. But if I pass them through a function first, I can get them to infer just fine. The function is a waste of space and I would like to achieve the same type inference without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get TypeScript to infer the tables first, then map over the tables as a tuple to columns of that table:

```
function listOfColumns<Tables extends Table[]>(columns: [...{ [K in keyof Tables]: Column<Tables[K]> }]) {
    return columns
}
```

The usage of `[...T]` to get `T` inferred as a tuple are called [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types).

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKghgIwDbQLxQN4Cgq6gZwGMALCAWzgC5Mc86BtQgeyQFcyA7a-YAJwEsOAcwC63PoKG1cAXyxysoSFADCLdhwA8MKBAAewCBwAm+WIhRR08ZBAA0UAHK6DR01ADWEEEwBmsegByIlIKQJErT28-AOCScjhwgD5I7DpgCwhqGDtpKA44MiyneSwsX1YOQmB+Jg4oJH4eAHlfNTZOfG1Ms31DEzMbFHoRJIAKZg6OfGp6ADoFjCh6AGkoQSiffyGIfDFVdU5u23xV0agZEQBKGjpeCGBWXnrJjXxSrGZp4ChgAEZUnkQglqGk6HgqFBAolcuC8AhqIEEIE8nIZAQ4DV8L5+LtzLYyl8eL8AEyAujAiigvJ0QiIwiBWFwqDGRHGFF0NEYrE4vE7MqNFptQ7TMb0PJguEZWzUf5MuEFIqIxJQAD0qqgADU4I1jKj5bdmdKULKSQa6IrioEGWqNdrdfqJTS8MbisAzc7cJbEXpAraoAB1ABKzUcAHFqABlYhMVhIYwcQI-BDQABuOv4es5WGuAG4gA)

Comment: Took me awhile to wrap my head around this, but I understand now. I wasn't understanding how `...{}` could be allowed, because the type argument in the variadic expression must be an array or tuple. However, the `[K in keyof Tables]` part includes all the keys of the array, including indices (`0`, `1`, `2`...) and methods (`length`, `pop`, `push`...), which means, even though it is expressed as an object, it is assignable to an array!

This is the good kind of "clever". Thank you!